# React setState hook not updating dependent element if passed a variable as opposed to explicit text

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm right on the verge of tossing React and just using vanilla JS but thought I'd check here first. I'm simply trying to pass the contents of a variable, which contains an object, into state and have that update the element that depends upon it. If I pass `setState` a variable containing the object, it doesn't work.  If I pass it the explicit text of the object it does.

Using React v 18.0.0

```
function buttonHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let tmpObject = {...chartData}
    tmpObject.datasets[0].data = quoteData.map(entry => entry['3'])
    tmpObject.datasets[1].data = quoteData.map(({fastEma}) => fastEma)
    tmpObject.datasets[2].data = quoteData.map(({slowEma}) => slowEma)
    tmpObject.labels = quoteData.map(entry => new Date(entry.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString())
    console.log("from button:", tmpObject)
    setChartData(prevState => {
        console.log("tmpObject",tmpObject)
        return tmpObject
    })

return <div>
    <button onClick={buttonHandler}>Update</button>

    <Line options={chartOptions} data={chartData}/>
</div>
```

When I run the above, the output of the console.log is exactly as it should be but the element does not update.  If I copy the object output from the console and paste it explicitly into the code it does work.

```
function buttonHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setChartData({...})
```

I've tried every imaginable variation on the below statement to no avail...

```
return {...prevState, ...tmpObject}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT:
As another test, I added the following HTML element to see if it got updated. It gets updated and shows the expected data.  Still, I'm having a hard time understanding why the chart will update if I pass it explicit text but will not if I pass it a variable.

```
<p>{`${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} {JSON.stringify(chartData)}`</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried this?
```setChartData(tmpObject)```
You have two console.logs, do they both print the correct data?

Comment: Yeah I’ve tried that. Yes, they both print the same.

Comment: If you console.log `chartData` inside the Line component, what does it look like?

Comment: <Line...> is part of the ChartJS library so I'd have a hard time digging into that to insert a console.log.  I did add another html element to see if it would update though.  See question update shortly.

Comment: I can't really say what's going on here. If the Line component seems to work with the initial data, there is a trick you can try to force it to update. If you pass a `key` prop to a React component, then the component will start fresh with the new data every time the key changes. If you have a string or something that will change when you update data, then try setting that as the key and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that of state mutation. Even though you've shallow copied the `chartData` state you should keep in mind that this is a copy by reference. Each property is still a reference back into the original `chartData` object.

```
function buttonHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let tmpObject = { ...chartData }; // <-- shallow copy ok
  tmpObject.datasets[0].data = quoteData.map(entry => entry['3']); // <-- mutation!!
  tmpObject.datasets[1].data = quoteData.map(({ fastEma }) => fastEma); // <-- mutation!!
  tmpObject.datasets[2].data = quoteData.map(({ slowEma }) => slowEma); // <-- mutation!!
  tmpObject.labels = quoteData.map(
    entry => new Date(entry.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString()
  );

  console.log("from button:", tmpObject);

  setChartData(prevState => {
    console.log("tmpObject",tmpObject);
    return tmpObject;
  });
}
```

In React not only does the next state need to be a new object reference, but so does any nested state that is being update.

See [Immutable Update Pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) - It's a Redux doc but really explains why using mutable updates is key in React.

```
function buttonHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  setChartData(chartData => {
    const newChartData = {
      ...chartData,  // <-- shallow copy previous state
      labels: quoteData.map(
        entry => new Date(entry.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString()
      ),
      datasets: chartData.datasets.slice(),  // <-- new datasets array
    };

    newChartData.datasets[0] = {
      ...newChartData.datasets[0],                   // <-- shallow copy
      data: quoteData.map(entry => entry['3']),      // <-- then update
    };
    newChartData.datasets[1] = {
      ...newChartData.datasets[1],                   // <-- shallow copy
      data: quoteData.map(({ fastEma }) => fastEma), // <-- then update
    };
    newChartData.datasets[2] = {
      newChartData.datasets[2],                      // <-- shallow copy
      data: quoteData.map(({ slowEma }) => slowEma), // <-- then update
    };

    return newChartData;
  });
}
```

Check your work with an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `chartData` state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log({ chartData });
}, [chartData]);
```

If there's still updating issue then check the code of the `Line` component to see if it's doing any sort of mounting memoization of the passed `data` prop.